# How can we host shiny apps that uses Rselenium in shinyapps.io?

Tags: r, shiny, shinyapps, rselenium

I want to host a shiny application which uses Rselenium for web scrapping. How can I host it on shinyapp.io?

Here is my code:

```
library(shiny)
library(RSelenium)
library(netstat)
library(tidyverse)
library(crayon)

ui <- fluidPage(
  actionButton("btn", "Click Me!"),
  textOutput("txt"),
)

server <- function(input, output, session) {
  observeEvent(input$btn, {
    #connect chrome driver
    client_server <- rsDriver(
      browser = "chrome",
      chromever = "119.0.5735.90",
      verbose = FALSE,
      port = free_port(),
    )
    
    # connect remote driver to client
    driver <- client_server$client
    
    driver$maxWindowSize()
    driver$navigate("https://google.com")
    output$txt <- renderText("Clicked!")
  })
}

shinyApp(ui, server)
```

I try to host it but it returns a big error. The error contains:

```
E: Package 'phantomjs' has no installation candidate## End Task Log ################################################################
Error: Unhandled Exception: Child Task 1355100025 failed: Error building image: Build exited with non-zero status: 100
Execution halted
```

How can I solve this problem and host Rselenium shiny apps in shinyapp.io?